# when is order of protection included in one's records?

Tags: criminal-law

In doing a background check on a person when will an old order of protection be discovered, and when will it not be?  Perhaps it is based upon the reason generating it or some formal wording inside the order?

Comment: There isn't actually a specific "permanent record" on a person, at least in the US. Whether or not it can be discovered at all may depend on the state (e.g. if one thinks a restraining order was files against John Doe in Moose County Indiana -- could be online -- vs Washington -- not apparently findable, and there is certainly no national repository of such information.